# Would it be possible to allow editing or formatted preview of bounty text?

Tags: feature-request

Would it be possible to allow editing - or at least a preview - of bounty explanations? It is not clear when writing the text if the markup rules are different, but I rely so much on previews that I could not see the formatting errors before submitting.

Alternatively, is it preferable for a bounty-setter to directly edit the question, as I did for [Meaning of polynomially bounded](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109352/meaning-of-polynomially-bounded)?